# Show that $\{a+t(b-a)\}=\{Ax+Bx+C=0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let be $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $a\neq b$, where $a={a_1\choose a_2}$ and $b={b_1\choose b_2}$. Show that
$$
G_{ab}:=\{a+t(b-a)\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}=\left\{{x\choose y}\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid Ax+By+C=0\right\}=:L.
$$

---

**My approach:**

We know that the solution set of $L$ can be represented by

$$
L=\left\{{u_1\choose u_2}+t\cdot {w_1\choose w_2},~t\in\mathbb{R}\right\},
$$
where ${u_1\choose u_2}$ is a particular solution of $Ax+By+C=0$ and $t\cdot {w_1\choose w_2},~t\in\mathbb{R}$ is the solution of the homogenous linear system $Ax+By=0$.

The idea is to find $A,B,C$ such that ${u_1\choose u_2}+t\cdot {w_1\choose w_2}$ attains the form of ${a_1\choose a_2}+t\left({b_1\choose b_2}-{a_1\choose a_2}\right)$, where $t\in\mathbb{R}$. For sake of simplicity we assume $a_1\neq 0$ and $a_1b_2-a_2b_1\neq 0$.

First,
$$
Aa_1+Ba_2+C\overset{!}{=}0\implies A=-\frac{Ba_2+C}{a_1}.
$$

Second,

$$
A(b_1-a_1)+B(b_2-a_2)=0\implies B=-\frac{A(b_1-a_1)}{(b_2-a_2)}.
$$
Third,
$$
A=-\frac{Ba_2+C}{a_1}=\frac{\frac{A(b_1-a_1)}{(b_2-a_2)}a_2-C}{a_1}\implies A=\frac{c(a_2-b_2)}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}, ~~B=-\frac{c(b_1-a_1)}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1},~C\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}.
$$
If we choose $A,B,C$ according to this rule we see that $G_{ab}=L$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether you can directly jump to the alternating representation of $L$. Rather, you can just substitute $(x,y) = (a_1 + (b_1-a_1)\,t, a_2 + (b_2-a_2)\,t)$, since $G_{ab} \subset L$:
$$
A(a_1 + (b_1-a_1)\,t) + B(a_2 + (b_2-a_2)\,t)+C = 0\quad\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\,.
$$
This means:

- $ Aa_1 +Ba_2+C =0$, and
- $ A(b_1-a_1) +B(b_2-a_2) =0$.

Can you proceed?

Comment: What is the problem if I represent $L$ by its solution space?

Comment: I just aware that assumption is too close from what we have to show.